# Run bash script from button html

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, linux

I have a html and form, with this 2 buttoms 
the principal it is for add the data form to the mysql.
but I neeed take a variable or input element and run a script each time the web user press the button "add" or "save"

example the form and button actual http://plnkr.co/edit/N8oQf6U9PjY6JlujiP46?p=preview

I take the code from here: `http://www.angularcode.com/product-inventory-management-using-angularjs-mysql-and-php-restful-api/`

So my question it is how add php on this button or it is possible to run a script bash with AngularJS?

the script show be run:

/cm-reset2.sh -r 172.2.2.48 -k snmpcomm -m 9999.9999.9999

where the 9999.9999.9999 it is product.name from the form.

the document it is a html file.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS helps build client side (frontend) but languages as bash, php belong to server side (backend). So if You have working PHP application and AngularJS application you should connect them by AJAX.

Other words after user click a button AJAX request must be sent to server side and on the server side must be run this command:

```
cm-reset2.sh -r 172.2.2.48 -k snmpcomm -m 9999.9999.9999
```

You can wrap this command execution by PHP script for responsing result to client side, for example:

```
<?php
    $command = 'cm-reset2.sh -r 172.2.2.48 -k snmpcomm -m 9999.9999.9999';
    $output = shell_exec($command);

    echo json_encode(array('result'=>$output));
?>
```

Comment: Hello,  and what I need to put on the button to run this?